# install kafka cluster (Bitnami) in GCP

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I am tying to install kafka cluster (Bitnami) in GCP. 
Successfully able to create topic on that,but while publishing the msg from TOPIC getting error:-

**rahuldalover@kc-kafka-0:~$ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092,kc-kafka-1:9092 --topic test**

> test
>   [2018-10-25 17:24:02,573] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker kc-kafka-1:9092 (id: -2 rack: 
>   null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-10-25 17:24:02,580] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: n
>   ull) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: Not clear why you are using localhost if the cluster is running in GCP

Comment: Also, see if this applies for your use case. Just replace AWS with GCP https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: After changing localhost :-root@kc-kafka-0:/opt/bitnami/kafka/conf# kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.128.0.4:9093 --topic test
>ff
[2018-10-26 05:36:25,529] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.Netw
orkClient)

Comment: Not clear why you are now using port 9093. Please read the post I linked to

Comment: Have you checked this guide? https://docs.bitnami.com/google-templates/infrastructure/kafka/administration/run-producer-consumer/

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply.
@Javier Salmeron ,yes concern is that when i am trying to produce/consume script getting the above error. IN GCP Env i see there are three VM instance   kafka-cluster-1-kafka-0 , kafka-cluster-1-kafka-1 and kafka-cluster-1-zk-0   .Create a test topic and then i am trying to produce/consume .

Comment: But could you confirm that the command shown in the guide works? Just to discard possibilities

Comment: @JavierSalmeron yes it works.